# Is reputation completely additive or is there a decay rate?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't find the explanation of reputation scoring over time. Does reputation decay over time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no built-in reputation deflation. There *are* cases where reputation can be lost (e.g. a reversed vote or a deleted post), but there are no processes in place to systemically decrease your reputation over time. Once earned, reputation is yours to keep.

Comment: Bounties DO lower your Reputation, right..?  I realize that is not "decay", it is a voluntary action (though people should read how it works to be sure they know half the value WILL go out if at least one item has 2 votes after 7 days).

Answer (score 6):

Every time I'm scanning the posts on meta, I read this as

> Is reputation completely addi *c* tive

And I answer myself that yes, yes it is.

Comment: :) Totally agree! (Wife waiting to go out for lunch on my holiday!)

Answer (score 0):

Added note to @RobertCartaino's answer:  [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

This tells you "all" about reputation.